# Is there an explicit word for non-abstract class?

Tags: terminology, concepts, naming-standards

I got mainly abstract classes in my project and there are a few other class which are using/inheriting them. When I'm writing the documentation I would like to specify that a part of it is just about the behavior of these non-abstract classes, but I found using this word silly.

I could just say it's a class, however an abstract class is a class as well. So I was wondering ***is there an explicit word/synonym for non-abstract class?***

SEO update:

What is the general name of non-abstract classes?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

They are typically referred to as [concrete classes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29#Abstract_and_Concrete)

> ...A **concrete class** is a class that can be [instantiated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantiation_%28computer_science%29), as opposed to abstract classes, which cannot.